# Draw tiles on Graphics without empty lines (gaps) between tiles

Tags: c#, graphics, bitmap, system.drawing

I am trying to draw a large image represented as set of tiles on a `System.Drawing.Graphics` surface.

All is great when I do not need to scale the `Graphics`. But when I do, I get empty lines between tiles.

How can I draw tiles on a `Graphics` without gaps between tiles?

Or shall I look somewhere else? Maybe you know non-framework classes, 3rd-party libraries etc. that I could use to overcome the issue?

Below are two sample tiles, image, showing the issue and code to reproduce the issue.

[image: resulting image]
[image: top tile]
[image: bottom tile]

```
float scale = 1.66f;
int width = (int)(128 * scale);
int height = (int)(256 * scale);
using (Bitmap result = new Bitmap(width, height))
{
    using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(result))
    {
        graphics.ScaleTransform(scale, scale);

        // tried lines below, DOES NOT always help
        //graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        //graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        //graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
        //graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;

        int top;
        using (Image bitmap = Image.FromFile("topTile.png"))
        {
            graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
            top = bitmap.Height;
        }

        using (Image bitmap = Image.FromFile("bottomTile.png"))
            graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, 0, top, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
    }

    result.Save("result.png");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I notice that you're creating bitmaps that have integral width and height by multiplying the scale factor by an initial width and height and then rounding (or likely truncating) to the nearest integer. However, you then do a scale transformation by the floating point scale amount, so the scale amount won't quite match the actual bitmap width and height. Maybe adjusting the scale amount used in the call to `ScaleTransformation()` would fix the issue?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but truncated width and height are used only for bitmap which is used as the backing store for the Graphics. so, I think it should not matter much.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, I managed to solve the following lines:

```
graphics.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
graphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?